# split for each statement into two divs ordered alphabetically

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have this code to echo out fields in a database alphabetically with headers for the letter of the alphabet they begin with. The information in the database isn't wide enough to fit 100% width of the page so I would like to split the information into two separate divs and float them side by side.. The CSS is easy, but I am unsure how to split them. There are 50 items in the database so I want the first foreach statement to stop at 25 and then carry on from where it left off in the second div.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $previousLetter = false;
?>
<?php foreach($this->clubs as $clubs) : ?>
    <?php
    $firstLetter = substr($clubs->club_name, 0, 1);
    if ($firstLetter != $previousLetter) {
    ?>
        <h3 id="club-link-header"><u><?php echo $firstLetter; ?></u></h3>
    <?php } ?>
        <a id="club-link" href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'club-description', 'action' => 'index', 'club_id' => $clubs->id));?>"><br />
        <?php echo $this->escape($clubs->club_name);?></a>
    <?php $previousLetter = $firstLetter; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code . I hope you can understand it.

```
<?php
    $previousLetter = false;
?>
<?php 
$i=1; // have a counter variable
foreach($this->clubs as $clubs) : ?>
    <?php
    $firstLetter = substr($clubs->club_name, 0, 1);
    if ($firstLetter != $previousLetter) {
    if($i==1){
        echo "<div class="left_class">"; // open left div
    }
    ?>
        <h3 id="club-link-header"><u><?php echo $firstLetter; ?></u></h3>
    <?php } ?>
        <a id="club-link" href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'club-description', 'action' => 'index', 'club_id' => $clubs->id));?>"><br />
        <?php echo $this->escape($clubs->club_name);?></a>
    <?php $previousLetter = $firstLetter; ?>
<?php 
    if($i==25){
        echo "</div>"; //close left div
        echo "<div class="right_class">"; // open right div
    }

    if($i==50){
        echo "</div>"; //close right div
    }

$i++; // increment the counter variable for each loop
endforeach; 
?>
```

Comment: it works.. with one major flaw.. I need the information on the right, to be able to float it without breaking my layout. However if I move the right class code up to the top as I thought the PHP breaks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put in another div after this will clear the floats.

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```